# How can I left align the table in html

Tags: html, css

I have html code which is used to display two tables. When I run the program the two tables appear one below the other, but I want the two tables to be on the extreme left.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 50px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    #table {
      margin-left: -850px;
    }
  </style>

  <body style="background-color: #E6E6FA">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Reportees List</div>
            <table id="employee_table" class="table table-hover" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>UserId</th>
                <th>Count</th>
              </tr>

            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="jiratable" style="display: none;">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary" style="width: 240%;">
              <div class="panel-heading">JIRA - List</div>

              <table id="Jira_table" class="table table-hover" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th width="80">Number</th>
                    <th>JiraNumber</th>
                    <th>JiraStatus</th>
                    <th>EmailId</th>

                  </tr>
                </thead>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sendmail" style="display: none;">
      <div class="container">
        <div style="text-align:right; width:100%; padding:0;">
          <button id="sendMail" style='margin-right:16px' class="btn btn- 
                primary btn-lg pull-right">Cancel</button>
          <button id="sendMail" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" onclick="sendMail()">SendMail</button>

        </div>
      </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

The output is:

```
                Number   Name   UserId   count
                 1      Ram     56782     1
                 2      Raj     56187     2
```

Expected Output is:

```
     Number   Name   UserId   count
       1      Ram     56782     1
       2      Raj     56187     2
```

Here for sample I am writing only one table output, but in actuality there are two tables each, one below the other.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? That can be added into the code snippet so that the Run code snippet section shows the output of what you have now. If so you can [edit] the question and add in a link to load the relevant portions of bootstrap that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `margin-left` and `margin-right`. You can also remove the `width` because tables always automatically are as wide as their content and there's nothing you can do about it.

```css
body {
  background-color: #E6E6FA;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

#table {
  margin-left: -850px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Reportees List</div>
        <table id="employee_table" class="table table-hover" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>UserId</th>
            <th>Count</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="jiratable">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" style="width: 240%;">
          <div class="panel-heading">JIRA - List</div>
          <table id="Jira_table" class="table table-hover" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th width="80">Number</th>
                <th>JiraNumber</th>
                <th>JiraStatus</th>
                <th>EmailId</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="sendmail">
  <div class="container">
    <div style="text-align:right; width:100%; padding:0;">
      <button id="sendMail" style='margin-right:16px' class="btn btn- 
                primary btn-lg pull-right">Cancel</button>
      <button id="sendMail" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" onclick="sendMail()">SendMail</button>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If the tables has to start from the extreme left then what is the property that must be used..Please advise.Thanks

Comment: The table is already at the farthest left possible within the Bootstrap structure you are using. Seems like you have no clue what you are doing.

Comment: If your original question is answered, remember to pick the correct answer. If not, explain how the answer does not solve the problem stated in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use float property. In this case, you want to float your element to the left.

```html
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <style>
      table{
      font-family:arial,sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width:50px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      float:left;
      }
      td,
      th{
      border:1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px;
      }
      #table {
      margin-left: -850px;
      }

     </style>

    <body style="background-color: #E6E6FA">
       <div class="container text-center" >
                    <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                       <div class="panel panel-primary">
                       <div class="panel-heading" >Reportees  List</div>
    <table id = "employee_table"  class="table table-hover" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <th>Number</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>UserId</th>
                    <th>Count</th>
                </tr>

            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

     <div id ="jiratable" style="display: none;">
            <div class="container text-center" >
                    <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-primary" style="width: 240%;">
                    <div class="panel-heading">JIRA - List</div>

            <table id = "Jira_table" class="table table-hover" 
               cellspacing="0">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="80">Number</th>
                                <th>JiraNumber</th>
                                <th>JiraStatus</th>
                                <th>EmailId</th>

                            </tr>  
                           </thead> 
              </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
           </div>

           <div id ="sendmail" style="display: none;">
            <div class="container">
             <div style="text-align:right; width:100%; padding:0;">
            <button id ="sendMail" style='margin-right:16px' class="btn btn- 
            primary btn-lg pull-right">Cancel</button>
            <button id ="sendMail" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" 
             onclick="sendMail()">SendMail</button>

            </div> 
            </div> 

            </body>
            </html>
```